# HP3PAR - Exporting volumes to Servers with standard NIC connection

Tags: hp

HP 3Par Management console only show the option to export volumes towards servers that are directly connected via iSCSI/Fiber.

When creating a new destination server, one must select how it is connected and only the iSCSI/Fiber ports show up as mandatory selection.

How can I assign/export volumes to other servers that are connected via ethernet ?

Answer (score 2):

Configure the 3PAR into NAS storage in order to go with file-level storage available utilizing Ethernet http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3954714&docId=emr_na-c03776930&docLocale=en_US

Comment: Have a read of the comments below, the guy know very little and wants to build an FC fabric is all, we thought he mean file services at first but he doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all iSCSI (and FCoE) *is* over ethernet, so your question doesn't fully make sense but let's assume you mean assigning files/directories over other protocols such as NFS and SMB/CIFS as volume sharing is a block-level mechanism supported by FC/FCoE and iSCSI. If you want these NAS protocols you need to buy the '3Par File Persona Software Suite' if you haven't already. Have you had any training with 3Par kit as untrained use could be dangerous to your data.

Comment: Let me clarify. Some of the severs have fiber channels directly connected to the HP storage server. For any of them, I can export volumes, but I cannot do that for any servers that are not connected in this manner (the rest that are only connected to the network, no special direct link).

Comment: That's still not remotely clear - do you mean you have an FC SAN with FC clients and you're having comms problems, or do you mean you want to do something via ethernet - they're not the same thing?

Comment: Yes, there are servers connected by optical fiber. The Storage has 8 ports connected to various servers. For those we can assign volumes by specifying the node-slot-port numbers (i.e. server1: 0.1.1,0.1.2). What I want is to export volumes to servers that do not have such a direct link (but are in our network).

Comment: Wow you seem so far out of your depth - you don't know the basics and your lack of knowledge will be dangerous to existing operations, get someone in who knows what they're doing, sorry to be harsh but we take this kind of thing very seriously on serverfault.

Comment: I understand very well how that storage works, just want to know if there's a way to allocate volumes anywhere.

Comment: @Overmind Like Chopper said - you need a NAS service installed on the 3PAR (file persona), and ethernet adapters installed in the array for this usage (NOT the management ports - it requires dedicated network cards). FC/iSCSI is used for block access, not folders and files. If you want more hosts connected to FC then you need a proper fabric set up - use FC switches instead of connecting hosts directly to the array. And please, hire a 3PAR consultant to help you with this. Call HPE.

Comment: Ok, well answer me this because you've been very unclear so far - you say that some clients are connected via 'optical fibre' - what protocol/s are these using, this is basic stuff but you've yet to say and it matters enormously (are they using FC/FCoE/iSCSI/CIFS/NFS etc.?) also you say you want to export to servers that aren't directly linked - we can't answer this until you say what protocols you're using and how you expect to connect those clients to the array.

Comment: I know that, I wanted to test if it works via general network, no dedicated anything.

Comment: @Chopper3 : the setup is like in the HP documentation: http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03605173&lang=en-us&cc=us%20

Comment: RIGGGHT - Finally! So you have only direct-attach FC clients, why was that so hard to drag out of you?? Ok, easy, you need an FC fabric - buy some FC switches, connect them to spare controller ports, install FC HBAs to your clients, connect them to the new switches and configure your zones/zonesets - job done.

Comment: You still did not understand. I want to allocate without connecting the other clients with FC HBAs. I want to use the standard NIC gigabit adapters the the have, that are connected in the same network as the storage.

Comment: You've been spectacularly unclear from the start, but as @pauska says you need additional hardware and software on the 3Par to do this.